# Mathematica syntax with & symbol

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have come across this expression in Mathematica:

```
oneStep[plus[e1_ , e2_]] := Flatten[{With[{a=e1,b=#},plus[a,b]]&/@oneStep[e2],
                                  With[{a=#,b=e2},plus[a,b]]&/@oneStep[e1]}];
```

but I cant seem to understand what does this &/ symbol mean in this expression.

Secondly: can this be written in more "human-friendly" way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&` signifies a [pure function](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html) (which is kind of like a lambda). Yes, it can be written in a friendlier way. As the linked documentation indicates:

```
body&
```

is equivalent to

```
Function[x,body]
```

where `x` is the argument.

The `/@` is a [map](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Map.html) (which can also be written in a friendlier way, as you can see from the docs).

Answer (score 2):

To supplement arshajii's answer:

```
veryLongFunctionName[n_] := n + n/2;
Map[veryLongFunctionName, {1, 2, 3}]
```

which returns:

> {3/2,3,9/2}

is longer than:

```
Map[# + #/2 &, {1, 2, 3}]
```

which is longer than:

```
# + #/2 & /@ {1, 2, 3}
```